# What is a good routine for running in the evening?

Tags: running, jogging, routine

I do racket sports 2 to 3 times a week, but I feel that I need some more exercise. So maybe jogging would be a good thing.

The basic things that I need to do in the mornings are:

- eating
- shower
- and now running

Obviously, the shower comes after running. But should you eat before or after jogging ? Is running as you get up healthy ? Any tips ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it both ways and see what you like.

[This article from Runner's World](http://www.runnersworld.com/nutrition-runners/fueling-runner-eat-or-not-eat) gives some things to consider when making this decision, but the decision doesn't make much of a difference, especially for jogs, rather than training.

If you had a late dinner or snacks in the evening, you probably won't feel the need to eat much before running.